# One section of my email template is not being responsive - Media Sizing

Tags: html-email

Someone please help! My company purchased an email template and all seemed well, but now they have requested that I make it so when the email is viewed as a web page at full size, it stays at the standard 660px. Every thing I have tried has resulted in either it resizing but no longer being responsive or vice versa. I know it's something simple, I know it's gotta be possible but I am just at a loss with this pre-purchased template. Any help to make this header media responsive but also only full size to 660 is appreciated. Code Below

```
</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .Hasna html { width: 640px; }
        .Hasna ::-moz-selection{background:#fefac7;color:#4a4a4a;}
        .Hasna ::selection{background:#fefac7;color:#4a4a4a;}
        .Hasna body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        .Hasna .ReadMsgBody { width: 640px; background-color: #f1f1f1; }
        .Hasna ExternalClass { width: 640px; background-color: #f1f1f1; }
        .Hasna a { color:#eb7260; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
        .Hasna p, .Hasna div, .Hasna span { margin: 0 !important; } 
        .Hasna table { border-collapse: collapse;}

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px)  {
        body { width: auto !important;}
        body table table{width:100% !important; }
        body table[class="table-wrapper"] {width: auto !important; margin: 0px 20px !important;}
        body table[class="table-inner"] {width: 100% !important; margin: 0 auto !important;}
        body table[class="full"] {width: 100% !important; margin: 0 auto !important;}
        body table[class="center"] {margin: 0 auto !important;}
        body td[class="center"] {text-align: center !important;}
        body td[class="rewrite_padding"] {padding:0px !important; border-left: none !important;}
        body img[class="img_scale"] {width: 100% !important; height: auto !Important;}
        body img[class="divider"] {width: 100% !important; height: 2px !Important;}
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px)  {
        body { width: auto !important;}
        body table table{width:100% !important; }
        body table[class="table-wrapper"] {width: auto !important; margin: 0px 20px !important;}
        body table[class="table-inner"] {width: 100% !important; margin: 0 auto !important;}
        body table[class="full"] {width: 100% !important; margin: 0 auto !important;}
        body table[class="center"] {margin: 0 auto !important;}
        body td[class="center"] {text-align: center !important;}
        body td[class="rewrite_padding"] {padding:0px !important; border-left: none !important;}

        body img[class="img_scale"] {width: 100% !important; height: auto !Important;}
        body img[class="divider"] {width: 100% !important; height: 2px !Important;}
        body td[class="one_third"] {width: 100% !important; display: block !important; padding-bottom: 20px; margin: 0 auto !important; text-align: center !important;}
        body td[class="one_third_last"] {width: 100% !important; display: block !important; margin: 0 auto !important; text-align: center !important;}

    }
    </style><!--[if lt mso 14]>
    <style type="text/css">
    td span {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    td a {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
        body {font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
    <!--[if mso 15]>
    <style type="text/css">
    td span {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

     td a {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
        body {font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:#ffffff; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <!-- START header -->
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="100%" align="center">
            <table ds-data-bg="1" bgcolor="#333333" class="ds-bg-module ele-active" width="100%" border="0" background="https://cs.homecity.com/images/email_icons/newsletterhouse2.jpg" align="center" style="">
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;">
                                        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://cs.homecity.com/images/email_icons/r" color="#333333" ></v:fill>
                                        <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                                  <![endif]-->
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <table class="table-wrapper" width="660" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding: 60px 20px;">
                            <table class="table-inner" width="640" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td valign="top">
                                    <table class="full" width="640" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                      <!-- START OF HEADER FOR LOGO & PREHEADER-->
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr class="ds-remove" data-remove="ds-remove-1">
                                          <td mc:edit="text_header" class="one_third" width="230" align="left" valign="middle" style=" margin: 0;font-weight: normal; font-size:14px ; color:#ffffff; font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; line-height: 18px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                            <multiline>
                                              <span class="tea14-content-editable">Newsletter issue #1</span>
                                            </multiline>
                                          </td>
                                          <td mc:edit="logo" class="one_third" width="180" align="center" valign="top" style="">
                                            <span><a href="#" style="color: rgb(21, 177, 210); border-color: rgb(21, 177, 210);" class="tea14-content-editable"><img src="http://cdn3.homecity.com/inc/skins/pt-1r/schemes/homecity/img/homecity-new-white.png" editable="true" alt="logo" width="250" height="" border="0" style="display: inline-block; border-color: rgb(21, 177, 210); color: rgb(21, 177, 210);"></a></span>
                                          </td>
                                          <td mc:edit="forward" class="one_third_last" width="230" align="right" valign="middle" style=" margin: 0;font-weight: normal; font-size:14px ; color:#ffffff; font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; line-height: 18px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                            <multiline>
                                              <span><a href="#" style="color:#ffffff; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none;" class="tea14-content-editable">Web version</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" style="color:#ffffff; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none;" class="tea14-content-editable">Forward</a></span>
                                            </multiline>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr><!-- END OF HEADER FOR LOGO & PREHEADER-->
                                        <!-- START OF HEADING-->
                                        <tr class="ds-remove" data-remove="ds-remove-2">
                                          <td mc:edit="heading" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" style="margin: 0; padding-top: 60px; padding-bottom: 20px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size:28px ; font-weight: normal; color:#ffffff; font-family: 'Nunito', Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 140%; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                            <multiline>
                                              <span class="tea14-content-editable">The Insider</span>
                                            </multiline>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr><!-- END OF HEADING-->
                                        <!-- START OF DIVIDER IMAGE-->
                                        <tr class="ds-remove" data-remove="ds-remove-3">
                                          <td mc:edit="div_header" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 20px; font-size:14px ; font-weight: normal; color:#ffffff; font-family: 'Nunito', Arial, sans-serif; line-height:100%;">
                                            <span class="tea14-content-editable"><img src="images/heading-divider-img.png" editable="true" alt="heading-divider-img" width="195" height="15" border="0" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr><!-- END OF DIVIDER IMAGE-->
                                        <!-- START OF HEADING-->
                                        <tr class="ds-remove" data-remove="ds-remove-4">
                                          <td mc:edit="heading1" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 0; font-size:18px ; font-weight: 300; color:#ffffff; font-family: 'Nunito', Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 140%; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                            <multiline>
                                              <span class="tea14-content-editable">Hi! I hope you've been well, I've put together some things I thought you might find interesting this month... enjoy!</span>
                                            </multiline>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr><!-- END OF HEADING-->
                                        <!-- START OF BUTTON-->
                                        <!-- END OF BUTTON-->
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr><!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                </v:textbox>
                          </v:rect>
                          <![endif]-->
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table><!-- END header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with a background image can be tricky but this template you bought looks decent. I made a few edits that I think will solve your problem. In the nested table that includes the background image I gave it this style

```
<style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;">
```

I also wanted that same effect to carry over into the outlook fix, so I changed the fill type to frame rather than tile:

```
<v:fill type="frame" src="https://cs.homecity.com/images/email_icons/r" color="#333333" ></v:fill>
```

Try this code in your body:

```
<body style="background-color:#ffffff; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <!-- START header -->
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="100%" align="center">
            <table ds-data-bg="1" bgcolor="#333333" class="ds-bg-module ele-active" width="100%" border="0" background="https://cs.homecity.com/images/email_icons/newsletterhouse2.jpg" align="center" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;">
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;">
                                        <v:fill type="frame" src="https://cs.homecity.com/images/email_icons/r" color="#333333" ></v:fill>
                                        <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                                  <![endif]-->
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <table class="table-wrapper" width="660" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding: 60px 20px;">
                            <table class="table-inner" width="640" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td valign="top">
                                    <table class="full" width="640" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                      <!-- START OF HEADER FOR LOGO & PREHEADER-->
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr class="ds-remove" data-remove="ds-remove-1">
                                          <td mc:edit="text_header" class="one_third" width="230" align="left" valign="middle" style=" margin: 0;font-weight: normal; font-size:14px ; color:#ffffff; font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; line-height: 18px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                            <multiline>
                                              <span class="tea14-content-editable">Newsletter issue #1</span>
                                            </multiline>
                                          </td>
                                          <td mc:edit="logo" class="one_third" width="180" align="center" valign="top" style="">
                                            <span><a href="#" style="color: rgb(21, 177, 210); border-color: rgb(21, 177, 210);" class="tea14-content-editable"><img src="http://cdn3.homecity.com/inc/skins/pt-1r/schemes/homecity/img/homecity-new-white.png" editable="true" alt="logo" width="250" height="" border="0" style="display: inline-block; border-color: rgb(21, 177, 210); color: rgb(21, 177, 210);"></a></span>
                                          </td>
                                          <td mc:edit="forward" class="one_third_last" width="230" align="right" valign="middle" style=" margin: 0;font-weight: normal; font-size:14px ; color:#ffffff; font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; line-height: 18px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                            <multiline>
                                              <span><a href="#" style="color:#ffffff; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none;" class="tea14-content-editable">Web version</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" style="color:#ffffff; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none;" class="tea14-content-editable">Forward</a></span>
                                            </multiline>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr><!-- END OF HEADER FOR LOGO & PREHEADER-->
                                        <!-- START OF HEADING-->
                                        <tr class="ds-remove" data-remove="ds-remove-2">
                                          <td mc:edit="heading" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" style="margin: 0; padding-top: 60px; padding-bottom: 20px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size:28px ; font-weight: normal; color:#ffffff; font-family: 'Nunito', Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 140%; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                            <multiline>
                                              <span class="tea14-content-editable">The Insider</span>
                                            </multiline>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr><!-- END OF HEADING-->
                                        <!-- START OF DIVIDER IMAGE-->
                                        <tr class="ds-remove" data-remove="ds-remove-3">
                                          <td mc:edit="div_header" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 20px; font-size:14px ; font-weight: normal; color:#ffffff; font-family: 'Nunito', Arial, sans-serif; line-height:100%;">
                                            <span class="tea14-content-editable"><img src="images/heading-divider-img.png" editable="true" alt="heading-divider-img" width="195" height="15" border="0" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr><!-- END OF DIVIDER IMAGE-->
                                        <!-- START OF HEADING-->
                                        <tr class="ds-remove" data-remove="ds-remove-4">
                                          <td mc:edit="heading1" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" style="margin: 0; padding-bottom: 0; font-size:18px ; font-weight: 300; color:#ffffff; font-family: 'Nunito', Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 140%; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
                                            <multiline>
                                              <span class="tea14-content-editable">Hi! I hope you've been well, I've put together some things I thought you might find interesting this month... enjoy!</span>
                                            </multiline>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr><!-- END OF HEADING-->
                                        <!-- START OF BUTTON-->
                                        <!-- END OF BUTTON-->
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr><!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                </v:textbox>
                          </v:rect>
                          <![endif]-->
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table><!-- END header -->

</body>
```